# How to run load file in k8s test

Tags: kubernetes

I am pretty new to both gingko and Gomega. Is there any way to run `/Kubernetes/test/e2e/perf/load.go` on a cloud-based cluster?

I know that it is for local cluster.

Comment: 1. That directory isn't present in the latest [v1.6.1](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/v1.6.1/test/e2e) so you'll need to specify what version of k8s you're using. 2. it would be helpful if you specified the _purpose_ of running that file, rather than a terse question about execution

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel I create a k8s cluster on other platform. I just want to get the API responsiveness latencies and try to lay out an instruction of what the size of master node is for some amount of master nodes. Could do give me some idea of which test file I should run and how to run it. Thanks.